# Iteration through items in a large API using ng-repeat with angularjs, my API is working, but results won't be fetched?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on quite a big fetch from a public API with hearthstone cards, The problem I am facing is
that the ng-repeat does not seem to be responding, it gives me:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: item in data -->
```

In the HTML code, and the HTML code inside the ul tag is not showing up at all.

**Index.html:** (The corresponding part of the HTML document.)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-16">
            <div class="prod-info-main prod-wrap clearfix">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="product-deatil">
                            <p class="price-container">
                                <span>{{item.Basic.cardId}}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
var produkterControllers = angular.module('produkterControllers', []);

// Skapar kontrollen produktController som hämtar data från js/data.json
produkterControllers.controller('minApiFunktionController', function myController($scope, $http) {
    fetch("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com/cards", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "8ad5a16c67mshed80ba15c31ab54p141ec5jsnfbff6480fd40"
            }
        })

        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log('this is the data, ', data);
            $scope.cards = data;
        });
        
});
```

I have disabled the service worker and all extra functionality to not disrupt with loading time for the API, but it seems that the HTML document completes the loading time before the API fetch is complete, and therefore it is not showing. This is my thought but after a lot of looking through the docs I am stuck at this point, What am I missing?

---

### Sample Data from the API

```
data = {
    Basic: [
        {cardId: "GAME_004", dbfId: "1740", name: "AFK", /* ... */ },
        {cardId: "CS2_041e", dbfId: "1853", /* ... */ },
        {cardId: "HERO_09", dbfId: "813", name: "Anduin Wrynn", /* ... */ }, 
        {cardId: "EX1_399e", dbfId: "1621", name: "Berser", /* ... */ },
        //...
    ],
    Battlegrounds: [{…}, {…}, {…},...],
    Blackrock Mountain: [{…}, {…},...],
    //...
}
```

Comment: your html is 'item in data" and the angular variable is $scope.cards

Comment: I see that the code injects the `$http` service. Did the code originally use that service? Did you change it to the Fetch API in a failed attempt to get it working?

Comment: Yes, in a failed attempt, i might have unnecesary code parts in the code due to trying a lot of different solutions, working my way to a solution with console.log, shall i remove the http service?

Comment: I really hate it when someone writes code that doesn't work, then they break the code more and then ask about the extra broken code.  The extra broken code distracts from the original problem. The `$http` service is best used for this application. Using the Fetch API doesn't help in any way and makes things more complicated because the Fetch API is not integrated with the AngularJS framework.

Comment: hehe, learning curve that has to be done i guess, thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the `$http` Service

The Fetch API is not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Simply use the `$http` service:

```
var url = "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com/cards";
var headers = {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "8ad5a16c67mshed80ba15c31ab54p141ec5jsnfbff6480fd40"
};
var options = { headers };

$http.get(url, options)
  .then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    console.log('this is the data, ', data);
    $scope.dataObj = data;
});
```

### Then use `ng-repeat` in a way that matches the data correctly:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, cardArr) in dataObj">
   <h2>{{key}}</h2>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="card in cardArr track by card.dbfId">
        {{card.cardId}}: {{card.cardName}}
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Georgeqwg, You have been really helpful, taking in all your feedback and learning!

Answer (score 1):

### ES6 promises not integrated with AngularJS framework

The ES6 promises returned by the Fetch API are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Use `$q.when` to convert the ES6 promise to an AngularJS promise:

```
var produkterControllers = angular.module('produkterControllers', []);

// Skapar kontrollen produktController som hämtar data från js/data.json
produkterControllers.controller('minApiFunktionController',
  function myController($scope, $http, $q) {
    var fetchPromise = fetch("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com/cards", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "8ad5a16c67mshed80ba15c31ab54p141ec5jsnfbff6480fd40"
        }
    })

    var angularPromise = $q.when(fetchPromise);

    angularPromise.then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log('this is the data, ', data);
        $scope.cards = data;
    });    
});
```

The `$q.when` method wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or **if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.**

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

---

## Update

Be sure to use the right variable in the `ng-repeat`:

```
̶<̶l̶i̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶=̶"̶i̶t̶e̶m̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶"̶>̶
<li ng-repeat="item in cards">
```

Comment: Thanks georgeawg, it is working better after these changes, however, it seems like i can't get the respone in my html code. I get the console.log('this is the data', data) response after the page is loaded after like, 2 seconds, and it is without any results in my html.. I've tried different combinations of {{ (angular scope call) }} formats..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change data to cards in your html:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in cards">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-16">
        <div class="prod-info-main prod-wrap clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="product-deatil">
                        <p class="price-container">
                            <span>{{item.Basic.cardId}}</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you just need to use [apply](https://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Also, your html is 'item in data" and the angular variable is $scope.cards

Comment: Avoid uninformative link phrases such as: click here, here, more, read more, link to, info, apply, etc.